# React front-end startup failure error 'umi' is not an internal or external command or a runnable program

Tags: javascript

Several attempts were made to reinstall the dependency, but after the installation, it was not allowed successfully and appeared as follows（ 尝试多次重新安装依赖 但是安装之后还是没有成功允许且出现如下）   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP0cq.png)

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle zjDemonstrationPlot@3.0.2~prestart: zjDemonstrationPlot@3.0.2
6 info lifecycle zjDemonstrationPlot@3.0.2~start: zjDemonstrationPlot@3.0.2
7 verbose lifecycle zjDemonstrationPlot@3.0.2~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle zjDemonstrationPlot@3.0.2~start: PATH: C:\Users\27632\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.17.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;E:\code\gitlab\codeing\3.12\zlink-front\node_modules\.bin;D:\app\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home\bin;D:\tools\Vm\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;D:\tools\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_331\bin;D:\tools\Xftp\;D:\tools\Xshell\;D:\tools\MAVEN\apache-maven-3.8.8-bin\apache-maven-3.8.8\bin;C:\Users\27632\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;D:\tools\微信web开发者工具\dll;D:\tools\apache-tomcat-9.0.68-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.68\bin;C:\Program Files\Pandoc\pandoc.exe;C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\inkview.exe;D:\tools\Go\bin;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\27632\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\tools\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\27632\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows;C:\Users\27632\go\bin;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin
9 verbose lifecycle zjDemonstrationPlot@3.0.2~start: CWD: E:\code\gitlab\codeing\3.12\zlink-front
10 silly lifecycle zjDemonstrationPlot@3.0.2~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'umi dev' ]
11 silly lifecycle zjDemonstrationPlot@3.0.2~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle zjDemonstrationPlot@3.0.2~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: zjDemonstrationPlot@3.0.2 start: `umi dev`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\27632\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.17.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:376:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\27632\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.17.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid zjDemonstrationPlot@3.0.2
15 verbose cwd E:\code\gitlab\codeing\3.12\zlink-front
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22631
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start"
18 verbose node v14.17.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.13
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error zjDemonstrationPlot@3.0.2 start: `umi dev`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the zjDemonstrationPlot@3.0.2 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Please dont't post images of error. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557